# Concentric matches with one expression

Tags: regex, autohotkey, pcre

What is the regex syntax for combining 2 expressions like a Venn diagram?

I have HTML with 2 table cells. Each of the 2 cells contains several table rows:

https://regex101.com/r/cTXwrT/3

This expression captures the 2nd table cell only:

`(?<=your mother)(?s).*(?=Monochrome)`

This expression matches table rows from all table cells:

`[A-Za-z].*Yoghurt`

How do I combine both expressions into one, so that I get the table rows from only the 2nd table cell?

I'm writing in AutoHotkey which uses PCRE for the regex engine.

I apologise for poor terminology— I've read up on recursion, back referencing, capture groups, atomic groups, etc but they didn't seem to apply.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do what you want with a nested capturing group. Here I capture everything between the `td` tags in an inner capturing group:

```
(?<=your mother)(?s).*((?<=\<td bgcolor="#F0F0F0"\>).*(?=\<\/td\>)).*(?=Monochrome)
```

You might need to tweak it a bit, it's a pretty scrappy regex, but it works for your current use case.

Reading the documentation for [AutoHotkey#RegExMatch](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RegExMatch.htm):

```
FoundPos := RegExMatch(Haystack, NeedleRegEx [, UnquotedOutputVar = "", StartingPosition = 1])
```

> If any capturing subpatterns are present inside NeedleRegEx, their matches are stored in a pseudo-array whose base name is OutputVar. For example, if the variable's name is Match, the substring that matches the first subpattern would be stored in Match1, the second would be stored in Match2, and so on. The exception to this is named subpatterns: they are stored by name instead of number. For example, the substring that matches the named subpattern "(?P\d{4})" would be stored in MatchYear. If a particular subpattern does not match anything (or if the function returns zero), the corresponding variable is made blank.

So you'd have to call it with `UnQuotedOutputVar`, say `Match`, and then look in `Match2` for what was captured by the second capturing group.

Comment: Cheers! That definitely got me further and gave me some ideas.